# Redirect page after press OK using sweetalert

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I've tried to redirect but it's not working. Can anyone help me, please?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(send_report($_POST['id_truck'], $_GET['id'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Success!","data successfully added","success");';
        echo '}, 200); window.location.href = 'report.php' </script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("failed!","Something wrong","warning");';
        echo '}, 200), ;</script>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes in a string wrapped in single quotes, escape them:

```
 echo '}, 200); window.location.href = \'report.php\' </script>';
```

**Edit:**

Now as your page is redirecting, your sweetalert will work but you may not be able to see it.

`swal()` returns [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which will be resolved when you click on OK button of sweetalert and thus we will have to wait for it to redirect the page thereafter:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
echo 'swal("Success!","data successfully added","success").then( function(val) {';
echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'report.php\';';
echo '});';
echo '}, 200);  </script>';
```

Comment: thanks @Sunny Soni, it's work but the sweetalert was gone.

Comment: @EdnelRotciv it should not, plz show your new code.

Comment: Ahh, i see, sweetalert is working but the page is redirecting now, i am updating the answer.

Comment: thank you for your help @Sunny Soni, it's completely work.

Comment: Nice, at stackoverflow community you can accept an answer which completely resolves your problem.

Comment: For me still does not work... Only with this line: swal('Registo Efectuado', 'XXX', 'success'); Can anyone help?

Comment: @White What issue you are facing? please elaborate it in a separate question.

Comment: @SunnySoni , it is working already :)